# C runtime error (undefined behaviour) for performing ++*(p++) on string literal char *p = "abcd"

Tags: c, pointers

Question 1:

```
int main()
{
  char *p="abcd";
  printf("%c",*(p++));
  return 0;
}  // Here it will print a
```

Question 2:

```
int main()
{
  char *p="abcd";
  printf("%c",++*(p++));//why it is showing error over here
  return 0;
} // Here it shows runtime error.
```

Can someone please explain to me why the statement ++*(p++) causes a runtime error.

Comment: For future reference, include the exact error you received. Just something to get used to for more complicated questions. It will speed up the process and you'll avoid getting downvoted.

Comment: Why write code that is unreadable?

Comment: @EdHeal: to compete in the IOCCC, of course :)

Comment: Include, what the expected result is. If you don’t specify what a program should do, there can be no bugs, no strange behaviors.

Comment: And which "runtime error" does it cause. In other words what is the output of your program ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *p="abcd";
```

`"abcd"` is a string literal and string literals are unmodifiable in C. Attempting to modify a string literal invokes undefined behavior.

Use a modifiable array initialized by a string literal to fix your issue:

```
char p[] ="abcd";
```

Comment: so which all literals we can modify in c.

Comment: @KerrekSB If you are going to be pedantic, do it with respect to the proper standard. A declaration is not a statement in C. Declarations and statements are neighbors within a compound statement (aka block) (C99 6.8.2:1)

Comment: @KerrekSB and strictly speaking it is a declaration statement in C++ but in C it is not a statement but a declaration.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I was referring to the [C\C++ standard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/). :-S

Comment: @ouah; *...but in C it is not a statement but a declaration* : I think in C its declaration as well as definition.

Comment: @haccks it declares and also defines and initializes an object but in the C BNF syntax, it's a declaration.

Comment: @dabs You can only modify structure literals. To make a modifyable string, initialize an array with a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

String literals are read-only. Any attempt to modify it invokes **undefined behavior**.
In second code you are modifying string literal which causes *undefined behavior* of the program.

Answer (score 1):

`++*(p++)` - This is equivalent to `++*p;p++;`

So here first byte value (character) of address stored in variable `p` is going to increment by `1`. And then value of variable `p` is going to increment, that means p is going to point (store) address of 2nd character of string literal (`"abcd"`).

Now go through the below two variable declaration.

```
char *p = "abcdef"; 
char p1[] = "abcdef"
```

- Here for first variable `p`, 4 bytes will be allocated in stack to
  store the address of the string literal `"abcdef"` and then 6 byte will
  be allocated to store the string literal (`"abcdef"`) in text segement of process memory. Always text segment is read only. So this value cannot be modifed.
- Then for second variable 6 byte will be allocated in stack itself to
  store the string (`"abcdef"`). Stack segment in process memory has both
  read and write access.

So performing `++*p` (modifying value in address) is applicable for variable `p1` but not appilcable for variable `p`.